# Indent before equal sign in .editorconfig

Tags: ini, editorconfig

Is it allowed to use indent before equal sign in `.editorconfig`, like in `php.ini`?

Example:

```
# editorconfig.org

root                      = true

[*]
charset                   = utf-8
indent_style              = space
indent_size               = 2
trim_trailing_whitespace  = true
end_of_line               = lf
insert_final_newline      = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed. all white spaces will be trimmed.